# Ruby Conditional-Assignment and Private Methods

Tags: ruby, memoization

From the code below, it appears the `||=` operator is being evaluated from outside of the class.

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar

  def baz
    self.bar ||= 'baz'
  end

  private

  attr_writer :bar
end

puts Foo.new.baz
# => in `baz': private method `bar=' called for #<Foo:0x007fd9720829a8> (NoMethodError)
```

Quoting from the accepted answer on [Official expansion of ||= conditional assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287341/ruby-official-expansion-of-conditional-assignment-operator):

```
In other words, the expansion c = c || 3 is (excluding bugs like in pre-1.9) correct.
```

Rewriting the `baz` method as `self.bar = self.bar || 'baz'` does not raise the error.

I am looking for a definitive answer on *how* and *why* Ruby is behaving in this way, since it seems counter-intuitive.

This behaviour is present on Ruby versions 1.9.3, 2.0.0 and 2.1.2, which leads me to believe this is not a bug.

Comment: `self.bar ||= 'baz'` means `self.bar || self.bar = 'baz'`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit but it still does not explain why it throws an error, does it?

Comment: @FarrukhAbdulkadyrov That was not explanation, that's for OP. who interpreted the syntax `||=` wrongly...

Comment: The [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907) was [fixed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/199f814f32e97b2fed528801c0ad2c84c1e5f8a6) an hour ago in trunk, and is [slated for back porting to 2.1 and 2.0](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907#note-1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like a [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907).

UPDATE: The [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907) was [fixed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/199f814f32e97b2fed528801c0ad2c84c1e5f8a6) in trunk, and is [slated for back porting to 2.1 and 2.0](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907#note-1).

Note that the problem is more general than that, it is broken for *all* abbreviated assignments, not just conditional abbreviated assignments:

```
private def foo=(*) end
public  def foo; 0  end

self.foo =  42

self.foo += 42
# private method `foo=' called for main:Object (NoMethodError)

private :foo

self.foo += 42
# private method `foo' called for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Yes. It is a bug. I am about to log it. But it is good before going there, I came here...